# Why does this error occur with .tranform(test_X)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-science, data-analysis

I'm using `MinMaxScaler` for scaling my data but I'm getting this error:

`NotFittedError: This MinMaxScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.`

Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occuring because you are instantiating a new object of `MinMaxScalar()` everytime you need it. You just need to create one object and use it throughout the code as per your requirement.

First you need to create an instance of the class MinMaxScalar(), like this

```
my_scalar = MinMaxScalar()
```

Then use this same object everywhere, instead of instantiating a new one like you have done in your code

```
train_X_scaled = my_scalar.fit_transform(train_X)

test_X_scaled = myscalar.transform(test_X)
```

See [this blog post](http://benalexkeen.com/feature-scaling-with-scikit-learn/) for an example of how to use different scalars.